# ADF not picking up correct source columns in Copy Data task

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my Copy Data source, I am using a query as follows:

[image]

You can see that I'm adding two additional columns to the result set that are not part of the base table. When I go to the Mapping tab, those two columns do not appear in the source. I assume they should?

Answer (score 2):

This is because your query is an expression rather than a literal string. In this case, if you go to mapping tab and click import schemes, it actually won’t call API to retrieve your schema because the expressions need to be evaluated at runtime. So the UI will just use the schema you specified at source dataset schema tab. In your case, you could add your columns there.